# requirejs error in my child theme

Tags: javascript, theme, magento2.2.2

I can't find where this error comes from my custom child theme.

> Error: Script error for: priceBox
>
> http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
>
> Error: Script error for: jquery/jquery-storageapi
>
> Error: Script error for: ko
>
> http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror

**Nb:** I also noticed that the error is present in all the themes even the Magento/blank or luma !

1. I created a [child theme](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-create-magento-2-theme.html) from **Magento/blank** parent `<parent>Magento/blank</parent>`.
2. I cleaned the `cache`, `pub/static`, `var/view_preprocessed/` except `.htaccess`,
3. I deployed the static content `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with "Error: Script error for: jquery/jquery-storageapi" after running "bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f".

What I did to resolve this was set mode to production

`bin/magento deploy:mode:set production`

then set back to developer

`bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

then redeployed to rebuild the pub/static files:

`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

then cleared the cache with:

`bin/magento cache:clear`

I double checked the folder permissions for pub/static and var/cache to ensure they were generated with the correct user/group and after refreshing the page (clearing browser cache) the errors were gone.